# Append content on random location with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, random, appendto

I need to display a list of items in a page, and this page is updated with AJAX. Every time a new item is pushed to the client I want it to appear at a random location inside my `ul list`.

Here's an example of the kind of list I'm talking about:
http://jsfiddle.net/XEK4x/

## HTML

```
<ul class="itemlist">
    <li>Item #2</li>
    <li>Item #2</li>
    <li>Item #3</li>
    <li>Item #4</li>
</ul>
```

## CSS

```
.itemlist li{
    width:100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 8px;
    padding: 4px;
    float: left;
    background: #dddddd;
}
```

Any ideas how I add new items at a random location in the list using jquery?
I know I can do something like `$(li_element).appendTo(".itemlist");` but this will append it to the bottom of the list.

Another thing that might be a problem is the fact that each `li element` is floated to the left. So when a new element is added in the middle, everything after that element will be pushed one spot to the right.

I could go with `several ul lists floated left`, and the `li's stacked under each other`, so when a new item is rendered the list simply get's pushed down, but if I do this at random, some ul lists could get longer than others which would also look strange.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var $lis = $(".itemlist li");
$lis.eq(Math.floor(Math.random()*$lis.length)).after(
                                            /* your new content here */ );
```

The [.after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/) method appends a sibling, so select a random element from the list of `<li>` items and use `.after()` on it. Or `.before()`.

P.S. Regarding a newly added item pushing the others to the right, why is that a problem? Isn't that normal if you have a horizontal layout for your list?

Comment: It is normal, but that's the reason why I'm not sure about using an horizontal layout. It's the easiest way though. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*9);
$(".itemlist li").eq(randomNum).append("HI");
```

Just create a random number in javascript. Then select that random element in the list and append the new content. Unless I am not understanding the question.

Answer (score 1):

with accepted answer a new element never gets inserted as first. the position where it can be inserted is number of elements plus one. between elements + beginning + end.

the code is not really nice but fixes it.

http://jsfiddle.net/XEK4x/38/

```
var $lis = $(".itemlist li");
var pos = Math.floor(Math.random() * ($lis.length + 1)) - 1;
if(pos != -1){
  $lis.eq(pos).after("<li>new</li>");
} else{
  $lis.eq(0).before("<li>new first</li>");
}
```