# How add a div inside Another div but in a random position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, random

I am creating divs dynamically and would want them added to the parent div in random positions not in the last position e.g.

```
                        var opt = document.createElement("div");
                        var txt = document.createTextNode(str);
                        opt.appendChild(txt);


                        //get the top and left positioning of the elements
                        var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (400));
                        var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (50));

                        opt.style.top = y + "px";
                        opt.style.left = x + "px";
                        opt.style.zIndex = zindex;   

                        $("#parentDiv").append(opt);
```

But problem is jquery's append function or add function puts the div in the last position on the stack. i want it put randomly between other divs...help

Comment: Do you mean that the div you last added lays 'on top of' the others or do you mean that the last added div gets added to the end of the document?

Comment: Exact duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002627/append-content-on-random-location-with-jquery

Comment: try to add opt.style.position="relative";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is already div:

```
var i = Math.round(Math.random() * $('#parentDiv').length);
if (i != $('#parentDiv div').length) $('#parentDiv div').eq(i).before(opt);
else $('#parentDiv div').eq(i - 1).after(opt);
```

Comment: this still won't cope with inserting the _first_ child into the parent.

Answer (score 3):

```
var $parent = $('#parentDiv');
var $children = $parent.children();             // get possible children
var n = $children.length;                       // there are n children
var pos = Math.floor((n + 1) * Math.random());  // and n+1 insert points

if (n === pos) {
    $parent.append(opt);                        // append after last
} else { 
    $children[pos].before(opt);                 // or insert before
}
```

**EDIT** I cleaned this up to merge together the no-children / last child case.

Comment: @S.McGrady  but you accepted the other answer?!  [which is incomplete, wrong, and also violates the DRY principle by calling `$('#parentDiv')` or `$('#parentDiv div')` at least three times?]